# Css text Positioning

Tags: css, text

I'm not sure how to word this question correctly, but I will give it a shot.

Using css, how am I able to keep elements (such as text) from moving when I resize my browser window? I need it to stay in the same position whenever I adjust the window size.

Comment: Can you push some code for better understanding

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need to use the [position property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position), or more specifically, absolute position.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this?  Sounds like a cross-browser/cross-resolution nightmare waiting to happen.  You can fixed position some stuff to always be in a certain area on the screen no matter what the size.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute`

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning

Comment: How come when I adjust the window size all the text gets crumbled.

Comment: What do you mean by 'crumbled'?